# python поиск строки в excel по слову и вывод этих строк

Tags: python-3.x

есть строковые переменные которые надо прогнать через excel файл и вывести все строки содержащие эти переменные начиная с этих переменных!

```
stroka_1 = "sdgfag"
stroka_2 = "fdwerf"
```

программа должна найти строки содержащие эти данные и распечатать строки с ними формотируя их от этих переменных - например так 
sdgfag 2113453etyrjeyjetyje
fdwerffdhgfgashegjhetjkrkry

Comment: Какой версии `Excel`? Если 2010+, то [`openpyxl`](https://pypi.org/project/openpyxl/) Вам в помощь.

Comment: да  у меня  2010+

Comment: пролазил весь инет + доки openpyxl не нашёл решения - наверно питон не умеет ничего искать в эксель

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python умеет многое:)
Код ниже:

```
import openpyxl as xl
import re

path = r'C:/Users/Desktop/Test_new/FindTest.xlsx' #путь, где к Excel файлу
wb = xl.load_workbook(filename=path, read_only=True)
ws = wb['Лист1'] #Название листа с данными

for row in ws.rows:
    for cell in row:
        if re.match(r'test*', cell.value): #вместо test ввести искомое значение
            print(cell.value)
```

Comment: raise ValueError("Colors must be aRGB hex values")
ValueError: Colors must be aRGB hex values

Comment: TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object